# Azure Site "Warm Up" After Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-devops

The Azure sites take a long time to re-cache and "warm up" after the deployment is complete. I want something to use Azure Devops to programmatically hit the CMS (content editor and experience editor) as well as the CD server to begin the re-caching process and make the environments usable again as quickly as possible.

Comment: Are you using App Services or VMs?

Comment: I am using App Services.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use the  section in your web.config.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/applicationinitialization/

This will load the pages you define when the app starts, so if you choose those pages wisely you can fill some caches.

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
    <applicationInitialization remapManagedRequestsTo="initializing.html" doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="true">
      <add initializationPage="/" hostName="www.xxx.com"/>
      <add initializationPage="/en/products" hostName="www.xxx.com"/>
    </applicationInitialization>
```